# How do you create a function that returns a pointer to another function with parameters already passed to it in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have some C code:

```
int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

int getVal(int a, int (*addToN)(int)){
    return addToN(a);
}

int (*addToN(int n))(int){
    //What to put here?
    //return addTwoNumbers(n);
}

int main(){
    getVal(1, addToN(1)); //Should return 2
}
```

When I call

```
addToN(5);
```

I want the return value to be a pointer to a function that, when called like so;

```
myFunction = addToN(5);
myFunction(10);
```

should call
addTwoNumbers(5,10);
is this possible?

I've tried typedef'ing a function type that takes only a single parameter and returning that type, but am unsure what to put in the body